# Switching between NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Maybe somebody will know, how to "tag" NSuserdefaults.

I have like 10 user defaults:
name
pin
etc...

I want to make another object, which would have the same defaults as the other ones (same variables but different values). Like a version, if `object == 1` then load one userdefaults and if `object == 0` another ones. But how to make it done?

Tried to make something like this

```
[NSUserDefaults setVersion:object.intValue];
```

But i guess this isn't the way to do it. So maybe anyone could help how to make it done?

To be more specific a simple example would help like how to do this:

Object (1 or 0)

```
[[NSuserDefaults  standartUserDefaults] setObject: @"something"
                                                 forKey: @"Name"];
[[NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] synchronize];

NSString *name = [[NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] stringForKey:"@name"];
```

How to set and get this Name depending on Object value?

Answer (score 0):

You could use persistent domains.

```
NSMutableDictionary *defaults = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] persistantDomainForName:@"aString"] mutableCopy];

// make changes to the dictionary here

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:@"aString"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setPersistantDomain:defaults forName:@"aString"];
```

Note that you'll need to be accessing all the defaults via the dictionary if you do this.

Comment: Thank you for your time answering. I'm very sorry, but i guess I lack the knowledge to understand and implement this. I'v added a simple example in my question, maybe you could get it working using your answer and I will grasp the idea finaly.